# Wrong app localization on the iOS App Store

Tags: ios, localization, app-store

An app I published on the App Store supports French only but is listed on the App Store as English only. There are no .lproj directories but the `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` key of the Info.plist is set to `fr`. Standard iOS components such as `MPMoviePlayerViewController` are properly translated in French.

Why is the App Store displaying my app as supporting *English* instead of *French*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the documentation from iTunes Connect *Resources and Help* under App Store Questions > Localization Display > App Store Language Display:

> **Where do the available languages displayed for my app on the App Store come from?**
>   This list of available languages shown on the App Store is based on your app bundle's localization (.lproj) folders. Missing, incorrect, or invalid localizations in your app bundle can be caused by misconfigured localizations in your Xcode project. You cannot change the languages shown on the App Store by editing the localizations on iTunes Connect.
>
> For additional information on localizations and localization (.lproj) folders, submit a [technical support request](https://developercms.apple.com/support/technical/) to Developer Technical Support (DTS). To receive support, you must use a Technical Support Incident (TSI).

So apparently the App Store ignores the `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` key and looks for .lproj directories only. You should probably try to add a `fr.lproj` directory with an empty Localizable.strings file.

Comment: Had the same issue and did the same in order to get it to work.