# Flutter App cannot be found in Apple App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, app-store, app-store-connect

We have developed an app with Flutter and want to market it internationally. We have received feedback that the app for iOS cannot be found in countries other than Germany (we are registered with Apple in Germany) (e.g. France and India).
However, this only applies if you search for the app name. If you search for the name of our developer account, you will find the app.

Target countries are entered in the App Store Settings.

We have contacted Apple Support and they say:
The problem is not the country as such, but the language setting of your app.
The languages in which your app is listed in the App Store depend on the localisation folders (.lproj) in your app bundle. Missing or invalid localisations in your app bundle are usually due to incorrect localisation configurations in your Xcode project.

We have checked our Flutter project and generated the localisation files via Xcode.
[image]
[image]

But still the app cannot be found in the Apple Stores outside of Germany (only if you search for our Developer Account name)

Comment: hey, check this out

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985232/wrong-app-localization-on-the-ios-app-store